# Solr - can't parse files using tika nested entity

Tags: solr, nested, entity, apache-tika

I'm trying to index some data from database. There are some linked documents for each page represented in database table.

I noticed that indexing generally works, but field 'text' from Tika is completly ignored and not fetched at all, without any reasonable exception in logs.

My data congig: http://pastebin.com/XdwenPTE, my schema: http://pastebin.com/zXEuFTHE, my solr config: http://pastebin.com/qLiuT0tq

Can you look at my configs and tell me if I ommited anything? When I make query on indexed data, there is no even present field 'text' - why?

[edit]
I changed file path passed to tika to:

```
url="${page_resource_list.FILE_PATH}"
```

But still file content is not indexed at all. Any ideas? I have some exceptions saying about files not found (it's good, because some files are missing) but there are no exception about any problems with existing files. And tika didn't indexed anything.

It seems to be the same problem as described here: [Solr's TikaEntityProcessor not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2953434/solrs-tikaentityprocessor-not-working) - but is this really not fixed yet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The entity reference for FILE_PATH is `${page_resource_list.FILE_PATH}`, not `${page_content.FILE_PATH}` (which only have CONTENT defined as a column).

You also have a [LogTransformer](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DataImportHandler#LogTransformer) that can help you by giving you better debug information about the actual content of your fields while indexing.

Comment: It was my fault.. file paths from dabase were wrong. However I have some other problems with multivalued fields but I'll create another question for it.